# save and retrieve overly changing code

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, version

I am new at java programming. I use netbeans IDE to make a considerably large project. So when I'm developing the project I keep changing the code to make it suitable the need. How do the best way to keep my code before being modified available? It is because I want to keep all of earlier version of my code so when I got error I can easily jump to the earlier version. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What you're looking for is called *Versioning* or *Version Control*. Check Subvertion (or SVN) as a simple start and/or if you feel like it improve it to Git or Mercurial. You'll also need a repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should seriously consider using a version control system like `GIT` or `SVN` especially now that you are working with large projects.

Read this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) about version control

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, version control is your friend. When using version control break your activities down into simple/small tasks. Concentrate on a single task only, and when working, commit that work together with a meaningful comment (your future self will thank you). The idea is to commit little and often. This is useful for two reasons:

1. if you need to throw away changes, you won't lose much.
2. if you need to understand what changes you made, there's less to understand

At some point you'll want to branch/tag your work. Tags are useful for marking significant moments in time (like a release) which should probably be frozen. Branches are useful for significant alterations/additions that aren't ready to be 'release ready'. When that work is ready you can merge your changes back in. This allows for a stable (trunk) version of your project and a work in progress (branch) version of your project.